# Google Play says my app is incompatible with some carrier models of a tablet due to manifest. What?

Tags: android, google-play

Why would my app not be compatible with only some carrier versions of a particular device, and how do I fix it? Check this out:

[image: wtf]

So my app is only supported if they have the v1a3g model or the viennalte model. But if they are using the verizon or att version for example, they can't download my app.

This is bothersome because I'm getting e-mails from users that have this Note Pro 12.2 tablet that want to download my app, but can't.

According to google, the reason is:

> This device model is not supported in your app's APK manifest and hence users of this device model cannot install your app.

Why wouldn't it be supported in my manifest? I checked, and my manifest doesn't exclude this device! Here's my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.my.app.censored">

<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.robertsimoes.shareable" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name=".myapplicationname"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeDark">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.samsung.android.icon_container.has_icon_container"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="censored" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.zendesk.sdk.support.SupportActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SupportTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.BrandedLaunch">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I've searched around stackoverflow for issues like this and people have suggested that some tablets cannot download an app if the apk size is too big (like larger than 20mb), but mine is only 7mb.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `<uses-permission>` elements, Google Play will automatically mark your app as being not supported on various devices. The solution is to use the `<uses-feature>` tag with `android: required="false"`. However the app needs to actually not need those features otherwise it will not function properly.

If you want to know why a particular device is not supported, click the little arrow on the right of the device listed in Google Play as is visible from your screenshot. Then click the arrow next to 'Track-level status'.

[image: reason device not supported]

Also keep in mind that devices that do not support the SDK version needed for your app will also be unsupported

[image: does not support sdk version]

Please refer to the link below for full documentation.

Here is what the official documentation says:
To control filtering, always explicitly declare hardware features in `<uses-feature>` elements, rather than relying on Google Play to "discover" the requirements in `<uses-permission>` elements. Then, if you want to disable filtering for a particular feature, you can add a `android:required="false"` attribute to the `<uses-feature>` declaration.
Source:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

Comment: I did click the arrow, but all it says is:

    This device model is not supported in your app's APK manifest and hence users of this device model cannot install your app.

So I should not be using <uses-permission> at all? Just replace it with <uses-feature> ?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The long answer is that you would need to design your app so that it does not crash when a feature is not available on the hardware. This requires some effort and also depends on whether it is possible for your application. Another way to think about is, there is a trade-off between putting in effort to make your app compatible with devices with fewer capabilities compared to just making all features mandatory.

Comment: @Photogd I added some images showing the display of specific reasons why a device is not supported. Be sure to click the arrow next to 'Track-level status'.